# Unexpected logback datatype

Tags: java, logback

In the process of moving our entire logging system to logback, I stumbled across the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE logging_event 
    (
        timestmp         BIGINT NOT NULL,
        formatted_message  TEXT NOT NULL,
        logger_name       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
        level_string      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
        thread_name       VARCHAR(254),
        reference_flag    SMALLINT,
        arg0              VARCHAR(254),
        arg1              VARCHAR(254),
        arg2              VARCHAR(254),
        arg3              VARCHAR(254),
        caller_filename   VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
        caller_class      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
        caller_method     VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
        caller_line       CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        event_id          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    );
```

Please note the definition of `caller_line`. Why would a database define what is an integer as a `CHAR(4)`?  Can anyone shed light on this?